# How to show two images in a view one after another and viceversa?

Tags: iphone

How to show two images in a view one after another,I have tow images named image1 and image2,when the user opens a perticular page it wants to show the image1 then after 2 second image1 dissapers and shows image2 then after 2 second image2 disappers and shows the image1 and go on. I hope you will understand my question.How to do this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please checkout MadhavanRP answers.. I guess its the perfect way of doing the repetation of image stuffs...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

[imageViewObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]];

NSTimer *ImgChangeTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.0
                                                  target:self
                                                selector:@selector(changeImage)
                                                userInfo:nil
                                                 repeats:YES];

}

-(void)changeImage
{
if (imageViewObj.image==[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image1.png"]) 
{
    [imageViewObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png"]];

}
else
{
    [imageViewObj setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Image2.png.png"]];  
}
}
```

Comment: imageViewObj is an Object of a UIImageView class . I have Taken a UIImageView thru the XIB.

Comment: it is not working ,i put a imageview in xib and create imageViewObj as iboutlet name

Comment: What is not working...?? can u set the image or there's no image at all..?? Check if u entered the Image Names correct..!!

Comment: yeaa its works perfect,but i want repeted animation.i want to contenusly changing the image1 and image2

Comment: it will continuously change every 2 second.. as the repeats property is set to YES

Comment: this is what i exactly  wanted,but how to enable repklted animation?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6332/discussion-between-stackiphone-and-bonnie)

Comment: but i set it to YES,but its not animating repedtly

Comment: ,sorry Bonnie its my mistak,i put the wrong image name.now it works great.thank you verymuch

Comment: Ur welCome...sorry for not seeing d chat invite earlier

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is -

```
- (void)animateImages:(NSMutableArray *)ppls index:(int)i
{
i += 1;
[imageView1 setAlpha:0.0];
[imageView2 setAlpha:0.0];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                      delay:2 
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn 
                 animations:^(void) 
 {
     [imageView1 setAlpha:1.0];
 } 
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) 
 {
     if(finished)
     {
         [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 
                               delay:0 
                             options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear 
                          animations:^(void) 
          {
              [imageView1 setAlpha:0.0];
              [imageView2 setAlpha:1.0];
          } 
                          completion:^(BOOL finished) 
          {
              if(finished)
              {
                  [self animateImages index:i];
              }
          }];
     }
 }];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a UIImageView to perform this type of animation. Set its property `animationImages` to the array of your images.

```
myImageView.animationImages=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:image1,image2,nil];
myImageView.animationDuration=1;             //in seconds
//myImageView.animationRepeatCount=0;
```

`animationRepeatCount` is 0 by default. You can set the number of times you want the animation to repeat